# Rails, can validate a user crating a record is admin, from the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, testing

I am attempting to make a new record object invalid if the user_id of the object is associated with an account that is not admin.

In the model I'd like to make a validation checks if the object to be created user_id.admin == true.

Neither of these solutions work:

```
  validates :user_id, User.find(:user_id).admin?

  before_save :user_is_admin, User.find(self.user_id).admin?
```

So, my question is, how do I write a validation that looks up the user and checks if they are an admin, and throws an error if they are not?

P.S. I am already doing admin checking in the controller as a before_action, but I'd like to invalidate the object if a non admin user manages to create one somehow...and for testing purposes.

If this isn't a best practice I'd still like to know a bit more about creating validity checks in rails.

Answer (score 1):

I generally wouldn't encourage doing this type of authorization at the model/database level. Rather I would suggest that you abstract your authorization code into it's own layer and handle this at the controller level, then rely on tests to verify that nobody can create an object except through the controller.

https://github.com/elabs/pundit is a great gem for integrating an authorization layer into your Rails application.

If you still did want to do this validation at the model level, you could do something like this:

```
validate :creator_is_admin

def creator_is_admin
    errors[:base] << I18n.t('object_class.activerecord.validations.admin_create_check_failure') unless User.find(user_id).try(:admin?)
end
```

Comment: Hmmm. It looks like that works fine in the model. I can debug in and have it lookup the user, but it's finding the wrong user, and when the tester tries it find's nobody and returns 
"   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=
    app/models/post.rb:12:in `creator_is_admin'
    test/models/post_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PostTest>' "
I guess I'll have to settle for doing it right right way :)

Answer (score 0):

I mostly validating before action goes to the Model, controller could be good for it.

```
  ###Post Model Sample

  validate :is_admin?
  def is_admin?
    unless User.find_by_id(user_id).admin
      errors.add(:not_admin, "The post not belongs to you || not admin :) ")
    end
  end
```